# SqlBulkCopy datatypes conversion

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have two DB tables, they have the same columns but their data types are different(E.g.: "Check" column is of a type integer in table 1, but varchar in table2). I am trying to copy the data from one table to another by using BulkCopy. I have a code like:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
    {

                    cmdSQLT = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + ColumnsNames + " FROM [transfer].[" + SelectedScheme + ".OldTable]", conn);
                    cmdSQLT.CommandTimeout = 1200;
                    reader = cmdSQLT.ExecuteReader();

                     sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("CHECK", "CHECK");

                    sbc.DestinationTableName = "[" + SelectedScheme + "_Newtable]";
                    sbc.BulkCopyTimeout = 1200;
                    sbc.WriteToServer(reader);
    }
```

I am getting an error saying

> The locale id '0' of the source column 'CHECK' and the locale id
>   '1033' of the destination column 'CHECK' do not match.

This is happening due to the data types differences between the tables. How can I make data type conversion in the previous code?

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the conversion on source select using a CAST() statement. 
However, if the target connection have access to the source database then instead of doing a SqlBulkCopy a single "insert into < target > select ... from < source >" statement would be a much more effective solution.

ie:

```
var colNames = ColumnsNames.Split(',').ToArray();
for(int i=0;i< colNames.Length;i++)
{
   if (colNames[i].ToUpper() == "CHECK")
   {
      colNames[i] = "cast(Check as varchar(10))" 
   }
}
ColumnsNames = string.Join(",",colNames);
```

Comment: Thank you! I've added the cast to my columns and it worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Might not be what you expect but for simply updating one table based on the rows of another table, improved performance and scalability can be achieved with basic INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements. For example:

```
INSERT tbl_A (col, col2)  
SELECT col, col2   
FROM tbl_B   
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT col FROM tbl_A A2 WHERE A2.col = tbl_B.col);
```

If it's more about column/table sync, the [Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) keyword could be what you are looking for.